# How would I transform this?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I would like to find a nice elegant solution to the following transform. How would this be best achieved in the most simple way optionally using the functional library Ramda?

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 'a',
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    routes: [
      {
        id: 'c',
      },
      {
        id: 'd',
        routes: [
          {
            id: 'e',
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const expected = [
  {
    id: 'a',
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
  },
  {
    id: 'c',
  },
  {
    id: 'd',
  },
  {
    id: 'e',
  }
];
```

Comment: Is Ramda required?

Comment: Hmmm, I would be interested in either please.

Comment: I updated the question so as to not stipulate using Ramda. THANK YOU very much for the time you have spent on this @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vanilla JS solution, using `reduce` and recursion:

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 'a',
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    routes: [
      {
        id: 'c',
      },
      {
        id: 'd',
        routes: [
          {
            id: 'e',
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const transform = arr => arr.reduce((a, { id, routes }) => (
  [...a, { id }, ...transform(routes || [])]
), []);
console.log(transform(data));
```

Alternatively, instead of creating new arrays each time, you could simply push to the existing array:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 'a',
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    routes: [{
        id: 'c',
      },
      {
        id: 'd',
        routes: [{
          id: 'e',
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const transform = (arr, pushTo = []) => arr.reduce((a, { id, routes }) => {
  a.push({ id });
  if (routes) transform(routes, a);
  return a;
}, pushTo);
console.log(transform(data));
```

With a variable for the nested property instead of `routes` hardcoded:

```js
const data = [{
    id: 'a',
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    routes: [{
        id: 'c',
      },
      {
        id: 'd',
        routes: [{
          id: 'e',
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];

const transform = (arr, prop, pushTo = []) => arr.reduce((a, item) => {
  const nested = item[prop];
  a.push({ id: item.id });
  if (nested) transform(nested, prop, a);
  return a;
}, pushTo);
console.log(transform(data, 'routes'));
```

Comment: Nice, how would this work if there was for example if there were other properties in the object and the property name 'routes' could be passed in to the function?

Comment: See edit, use bracket notation if you want the name of the property with nested objects inside to be specified at runtime

Answer (score 1):

A solution in JS without too much spreading

```js
function getFlat(array = []) {
    return array.reduce((r, { id, routes }) => r.concat({ id }, getFlat(routes)), []);
}

const data = [{ id: 'a', }, { id: 'b', routes: [{ id: 'c', }, { id: 'd', routes: [{ id: 'e', }] }] }];

console.log(getFlat(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With rest parameters for objects for getting all properties of an object, exept `routes` for return.

```js
function getFlat(array = []) {
    return array.reduce((r, { routes, ...o }) => r.concat(o, getFlat(routes)), []);
}

const data = [{ id: 'a', foo: 1 }, { id: 'b', routes: [{ id: 'c' }, { id: 'd', routes: [{ id: 'e', bar: 2 }] }] }];

console.log(getFlat(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the other suggestions here is to use [`R.chain`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) to flatten each nested set of routes.

```
const fn = R.chain(({routes = [], ...rest}) => [{...rest}, ...fn(routes)])
```

This approach will also be possible to achieve with plain JS once [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) becomes readily available.

```
const fn = (xs = []) => xs.flatMap(({routes, ...rest}) => [{...rest}, ...fn(routes)])
```